# Safari WebRTC error... "Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description:

Tags: safari, webrtc, janus-gateway

I am using the janus gateway videoroom plug-in. but in safari I get the error WebRTC error ... "Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send parameters .." in remotefeed.createanster method. I did VideoCodec h264 did not fix. My sdp package is as follows. Please can you help?

```
"v=0
o=- 1590927151096625 1 IN IP4 51.210.46.15
s=VideoRoom 101617
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS janus
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 51.210.46.15
a=sendonly
a=mid:audio
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:58nV
a=ice-pwd:CjVSNWGDvqbie3U6Kzb1yV
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 12:62:34:F6:01:E2:77:0D:80:44:9A:09:E8:7E:39:D6:8F:8B:B6:BF:BE:53:E1:C0:C8:06:1E:4F:2E:53:25:37
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=msid:janus janusa0
a=ssrc:1489843321 cname:janus
a=ssrc:1489843321 msid:janus janusa0
a=ssrc:1489843321 mslabel:janus
a=ssrc:1489843321 label:janusa0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2015363327 51.210.46.15 44468 typ host
a=end-of-candidates
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 107 108
c=IN IP4 51.210.46.15
a=sendonly
a=mid:video
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:58nV
a=ice-pwd:CjVSNWGDvqbie3U6Kzb1yV
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 12:62:34:F6:01:E2:77:0D:80:44:9A:09:E8:7E:39:D6:8F:8B:B6:BF:BE:53:E1:C0:C8:06:1E:4F:2E:53:25:37
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:107 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:107 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:107 goog-remb
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=fmtp:107 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:108 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:108 apt=107
a=ssrc-group:FID 1955475390 4119939419
a=msid:janus janusv0
a=ssrc:1955475390 cname:janus
a=ssrc:1955475390 msid:janus janusv0
a=ssrc:1955475390 mslabel:janus
a=ssrc:1955475390 label:janusv0
a=ssrc:4119939419 cname:janus
a=ssrc:4119939419 msid:janus janusv0
a=ssrc:4119939419 mslabel:janus
a=ssrc:4119939419 label:janusv0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2015363327 51.210.46.15 44468 typ host
a=end-of-candidates
" = $1
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the video codec **profile-level-id**, **profile-level-id 42001f** is not supported by the Safari browser. this is based on my personal experience. in order to complete handshaking between two nodes at least one codec (for both video and audio) should match between both the nodes.

It seems in SDP Janus is sharing only one video codec. which is **H264 of clock cycle 9000 and profile-level-id=42001f** you can [read here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/15615289761/)  to understand more about profile level id.

this is my observation of support of browser with h264 with **profile-level-id**, Feel free to add your observation here
Chrome(MacOS) =>

| Browser | Operating System | codec | level-asymmetry-allowed | packetization-mode | profile-level-id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | MacOS | H264/9000 | 1 | 0,1 | 42001f, 42e01f |
| Safari | MacOS | H264/9000 | 1 | 1 | 640c1f, 42e01f |